# Open Chrome extension from link on website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to open a Chrome extension (acting as a background page) from a link on my website.

Things I have tried:

- Make an `a` tag linking to the extension's main HTML page.
- Sending the user to a page which does a 302 redirect to the HTML page.
- Using Javascript to redirect the user, with `window.location = ...`

All of these do not work and open an `about:blank` page instead. The exception (which seems odd) is when I use strategy #2 and the link is opened from my desktop mail client.

Any ideas as to how this can be accomplished? Requesting the `tabs` permission is not possible in our case.

Comment: What is your OS / Chrome version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading about  [message passing from a webpage to a background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage)  of your extension (sounds like a thing you want to accomplish).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the taregt HTML file in the **[`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)** section of your manifest. E.g.:

**Extension file-structure:**

```
          root-dir/
           |_____manifest.json
           |_____content.js
           |_____myfile.html
```

**content.js:**

```
/* Append a link to the web-page's body */
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = chrome.extension.getURL("myfile.html");
a.target = "_blank";
a.textContent = "My HTML file";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

    "web_accessible_resources": ["myfile.html"]
}
```